# Django Static js files not working

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

Well my template code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
{% load staticfiles %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'website/staffaddproblem.js' %}"></script>
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <link href="{% static 'website/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
        body
</body>
<html>
```

As you can see it has a css file. which is working properly, but java script file does not work.
when i load the page its source looks like this.
[image]

When i click the link it loads the file too its there its linking fine but its not working . there is no problem in code js code working fine when written in same file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you changed the `settings.py` file to include staticroot?

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Here's a part of my template which works with both `js` and `css` files.

```
{% load static %}
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/materialize.min.css' %}">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/stylesheet.css' %}">
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js' %}"></script>
<title>
```

The directories are as follows:

```
 - static
     -js
         - jquery-1.11.3.min.js
     -css     
         - stylesheet.css
         - materialize.min.css
 - templates
     -index.html
```

Comment: Sorry my mistake just putted code in document.ready and its working fine now.

Comment: @AyubKhan hahaha. No problem. Please accept this answer as the correct one if it helped you in any way.